# Car subwoofer wiring

Tags: amplifier, automotive

Im not much of an audiophile or audio technician and Im pretty much ok with the sound my car has, except the low frequency output. I don't want to mess up with wiring and speakers or change the head unit,  what Im trying to do is somehow inline an active sub to the rear speakers, like connect the amplifier to the speakers (1 or both, series or parallel, no idea) because the head unit (basic bmw e39 becker casette radio with a headphone amplifier aux port added) obviously doesn't have a sub output (does it?).

Im just curious what happens if I add the amp to the wires of the rear speakers as a diy (power/safety wise) or should I stop fooling around and get someone who knows their job to do this?

Comment: Get someone who knows what they're doing to do it. You're going to need to add wires to the battery for the amplifier, if they're not fused properly you could burn your car out.

Comment: I have an IT engineer degree and Im over 30y.o.. Im all good with wiring, fuses and switches of all sorts :) I just don't want to invest any time to tear apart half the car for cables and stuff, I just want to know if my logic is correct and get some generic directions

Comment: Do not plug in amplified signals to a line level input! You may damage both devices!

Comment: so amplifier takes only weak signal, like from headphones right? what other options do I have if HU doesn't have sub out?

Comment: don't forget that you can hook everything up and test it outside of the car .... do the actual install after everything works

Answer (score 1):

You can buy an amplifier that has speaker level inputs, otherwise, you can use a line output converter between the speaker wires and the amp inputs.  You will also need to run power from the battery to the amplifier.  Be sure to carefully follow installation instructions with regard to supply wire sizing, fusing and routing. It's not that hard to DIY, but a professional install shouldn't be very expensive

Comment: the problem with professionals is that they try to make it look that you're so obsolete that it's a shame, sell you stuff or convince you to get stuff you don't really need, they'll have you replace the stock speakers, which requires a new head unit, which requires tearing the car apart entirely just so it's "done properly". Been there. Im absolutely ok with my factory setup, I don't like it louder or clearer just a little more bass while I play the radio or phone would be great. can you give me a sample of such a product and explain the key differences to identify one?